# Storing address in a mapping

Tags: solidity, addresses, mapping

Is this code sufficient to store an address in a mapping?

```
mapping (address => bool) public registeredAddresses;

function register(address addr) public {
        // check if Address hasn't been registered before 
        require(!registeredAddresses[addr]); 
        // only the address owner can register it
        require(msg.sender == addr);
        registeredAddresses[addr] = true;
    }
```

New to solidity/dapp development and not sure what context this function would be called. How exactly would the address that calls this `register` function get added to the mapping?

Would the `registeredAddresses[addr] = true;` line need to be changed to `registeredAddresses[msg.sender] = true;` and remove the arguments to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the registeredAddresses[addr] = true; line need to be changed to registeredAddresses[msg.sender] = true; and remove the arguments to the function?

It wouldn't *need* to, but since you're requiring `addr` to be equal to `msg.sender`, there's no reason of not doing so, plus it would save gas. Otherwise your code i perfectly fine

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand and why changing `addr` to `msg.sender` would save gas?

Comment: calldata costs quite a bit of gas, and the process of first checking  that it's equal to msg.sender, then storing it into memory, then retrieving it to then use it as the mapping keys will cost a few units too, when `msg.sender` translates to a opcode that only costs 2 gas.

Answer (score 0):

No need to check `require(msg.sender == addr)`

Eg.

```
function register() public {
   // check if Address hasn't been registered before 
   require(!registeredAddresses[msg.sender]); 
   registeredAddresses[msg.sender] = true;
}
```

If only owner of the contract can add address then you can do like this

```
.......
address public owner;
function register(address addr) public {
    // check if Address hasn't been registered before 
    require(!registeredAddresses[addr]); 
    // only the contract owner can create new register
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    registeredAddresses[addr] = true;
 }
```